# Extracting polygons from mbtiles

Tags: polygon, spatialite, sqlite, mbtiles, extract

Currently, one can extract features within a bounding box from an mbtiles file using tilelive-copy. However there is no way to extract features within a polygon from an mbtiles file.

The mbtiles-extracts file which comes closest returns **all of the** tile data if a tile intersects a polygon, but does not return features constrained to the polygon.

1. Are there libraries that can do this? Take an mbtiles file and a geojson file containing a polygon feature as input and output all the features in the mbtiles file present within the polygon?
2. Is there a way to do this with sqlite3 and spatialite?